# Modificar la clase asignandole el valor de un contador ( Jquery y Php )

Tags: php, jquery

Como puedo asignarle un número obtenido del contador  a cada elemento  `div` ; es decir; a la clase elemento  ponerle el contador  obtenido del recorrido  de la base de datos.

*Campos Html*

```
<div id="campoBusq"></div>
    <div id="categoria">';
        include("selectCategJquery.php");
    </div>
</div>
```

*Usando  llamadas con php para buscar  la manera de asignarle  un contador al nombre de la clase*

```
<?php 
    include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>

<script>
  $('document').ready(function() {

     <?php 
        $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

       while ($paisBuscado = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
          $categoria = utf8_encode($paisBuscado['idCategoria']);
          for (var i=0; i<=$categContador.length; i++) {        
      ?>

       var categoriajs = "<?php echo $categoria ?>";
       var categContadorjs = "<?php echo $categContador ?>";

       $('#categoria').append('<option class="elemento'+" "+''+categContadorjs+'" iden="'+categContadorjs+'" value="'+ categoriajs +'" >' + categoriajs +'</option>');

  <?php  
      }
    }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
  ?>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
       var e = $(this).clone();
       var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");

       if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
          document.write($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length);
       }else{
         $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
       } 
   });

    $('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
       $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: las clases que quieres tienen la palabra "elemento", luego un espacio y luego el valor de categContadorjs? o tienen todo pegado

Comment: es algo asi lo que busco: original class="elemento"; y quiero asignarle el contador para hacerle un identificador de esta manera class="elemento 2";

Comment: Además... hay otro problema. Si más arriba estás haciendo un FOR, significa que `$categContador` es un array

Comment: quieres simplemente un contador incremental que parta del 1, y añadir su valor a la clase?

Comment: si amigo, hay ahy un error no lo e desifrado aun

Comment: exacto eso mismo

Answer (score 0):

De lo aclarado en los comentarios, quieres que en cada iteracion del bucle `while` de la consulta SQL, el resultado que se va escribiendo tenga un correlativo añadido en la forma de la variable `categContadorjs`

Yo lo haría sin usar ese `for`, que no tiene nada que hacer ahí.

```
<?php 
   $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
   $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

   $categContador=0;
   while ($paisBuscado = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
      $categContador++;
      $categoria = utf8_encode($paisBuscado['idCategoria']);

?>  

   var categoriajs = "<?php echo $categoria ?>";
   var categContadorjs = "<?php echo $categContador ?>";

   $('#categoria').append('<option class="elemento ' + categContadorjs + '" iden="' + categContadorjs + '" value="' + categoriajs + '" >' + categoriajs +'</option>');

<?php  
   }

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
$conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: `class="elemento 1"` en realidad son dos clases. Pero quería cerciorarme que el amasijo de comillas tuviera como propósito separar la palabra elemento de lo que viene después.

Comment: Esperen un momento porque no quiere traerme nada de la base de datos que ante si lo hacia

Comment: no será que copiaste y pegaste mi código tal cual? mira que el mio no incluye conexión.php

Comment: solo copie el trozo de codigo que me enviaste, si gusta se los envio

Answer (score 0):

Está linea está mal:

```
$('#categoria').append('<option class="elemento'+" "+''+categContadorjs+'" iden="'+categContadorjs+'" value="'+ categoriajs +'" >' + categoriajs +'</option>');
```

Deberías cambiarlo por

```
$('#categoria').append('<option class="elemento '+categContadorjs+'" iden="'+categContadorjs+'" value="'+ categoriajs +'" >' + categoriajs +'</option>');
```

En ese caso, cada option quedaría conformado de la siguiente manera:

```
<option class="elemento 1" iden="1" value="1" >1</option>
<option class="elemento 2" iden="2" value="2" >2</option>
<option class="elemento ..n" iden="..n" value="..n" >..n</option>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad!

Exitos!